# What should I do when a crucial group in a larger dataset has not been recorded when performing regression analysis?

Tags: regression, missing-data

I've attached a picture of the data I'm analysing; this concerns two types of anaesthesia (A and B) at varying dosages (Low - L, Moderate - M and High - H). I'm trying to ascertain what the benefit of changing the method of anaesthetic administration, however the high dose of anaesthetic A method was not recorded. Will this mean that using the data from the high dose of anaesthetic B will lead to spurious conclusions if I include it in my regression?

[image: The data this post is concerned with]

Apologies if something similar has been covered in a previous question, I've no doubt it has but I couldn't find what I was after.

Comment: How do you asses the costs and benefits? I guess that time plays a role (which is obviously lowest in a high dose with method B), but does the combination of the dose and type of method play a (variably) role as well?

Comment: Without doing the calculations I observe, roughly, that you have some cross effect (aside from small statistical significance but this is difficult to *see* without doing the calculations). With a low dose the method a is slower than method b, the opposite is true with a medium dose. So it is dose dependent. The only way that you could 'resolve' the missing data for the high dose is when you would have a model that could fill the gap, or otherwise you would need to get more data. Obviously there is some relationship with the dose, but it is not a simple relationship and this data does not help